# NDepend cannot pick up new reference assembly automatically

Tags: ndepend

I have a NDepend project that is using in automatic build process. When a developer adds one more assembly to the project, NDepend cannot pick up and analyze that assembly automatically. I can see the new assembly only when I add manually into NDepend project. How can I configure in NDepend project so that it will pick up new reference assembly and analyze automatically. Is there anyways to do it or am I something wrong in using NDepend?
Thanks,
ant.

Answer (score 0):

> When a developer adds one more assembly to the project,

I guess you mean When a developer adds one more assembly to the Visual Studio solution,
in that case indeed, this is a feature request for future NDepend version.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Now I wrote small app to modify NDepend project and the problem solved. I also want to suggest to add a feature that user can specify a list to directories to pick up assemblies. In my company, we are using NDepend to monitor code quality in every build.

Comment: >user can specify a list to directories to pick up assemblies

Have you look at Project properties > Code to Analyze > Folders ?

Comment: there is no auto pickup, i need to add new assemblies manually to the project.